# Save data from selective tables with pg_dump

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

I'm working with `pg_dump`. I was able to make the whole dump of my database. Had no problem with this. But now I have to make a 'partial' dump. A have 41 tables and I need to dump all of them but dumping the data only for  21 of them. So 20 of them are only schemes with no data. Is `--exclude-table-data` a good thing to use in my situation? Or there are any other options? Thanx in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`--exclude-table-data` seems perfect for your use-case. You can also restore a specific table from a full pg_dump using pg_restore and `--table` option.